# How do I make a window the active window in a Cocoa multi window app?

Tags: cocoa, multi-window

I have a multi window Cocoa app, implemented using the techniques described in an answer to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688137/what-is-the-best-approach-for-a-multi-window-document-based-cocoa-app).

All works fine, however windows opened after the initial window come up and are shown front, but their state is not active (everything greyed). I have to explicitly click inside their frame to make them the active window.

My checks so far:

- I've tried `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` but that doesn't make any difference.
- The file owner in the NIB is set to the corresponding controller class of the window.
- I can see in the Debugger that the instance of each controller is actually the owner of the corresponding window.
- The solution suggested by NSThread does not make the the window key window.
- The method `canBecomeKeyWindow` returns `NO` although the window is an instance of NSWindow.
- The window has a title bar and is resizable.

What do I need to do to show subsequent windows in an active state?

EDIT:

I subclassed `NSWindow` with `SecondaryWindow` and override `canBecomeKeyWindow` to return `YES`. I changed to XIB to use the newly created subclass of `NSWindow`. Stepped through the code with the debugger, but still the window does not become the key window.

Comment: Does `canBecomeKeyWindow` return YES?

Comment: Hmm.. no, it returns NO. I double checked the XIB file and the window is an instance of NSWindow according to IB which should return YES by default implementation according to the docs...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[previousWindow orderBack];
[previousWindow resignKeyWindow];
[newWindow orderFront];
[newWindow makeKeyWindow];
```

- An window can become key window if it have title bar or a resize bar.

If your application window don't have title bar or resize window then
   it can't become key window.

Comment: No, that doesn't do it either... New window has title bar and resize bar, so no show stopper there.